# Why is this variable sometimes undefined?

Tags: google-apps-script

So this function gets a folder, gets the subfolders, pushes some information to an array and then pastes the array into my spreadsheet.

It fails at a weird point about 2-5% of the time, and the attempts I have made to error catch it earlier just don't work. why/how!

```
function getFileCount(gdrive,level,fullpath){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(gdrive);
  var fileCount = 0;


  //append the subfolders to the sheet 
  var folders = folder.getFolders();
  var result = [];
  while (folders.hasNext()){
    var folder = folders.next();
    var path = fullpath + " > " +folder.getName();
    result.push([(level+1),folder.getId(), path,"?"]);
  }
  if (result == []) return fileCount;
  if (result == undefined) {console.log("Why the hell is it undefined?"+folder.getName()); return fileCount;}
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getSheetByName("FoldersPlusCounts");
  var end = ss.getLastRow()+1;  
  try{ss.getRange(end, 1,result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);}catch(e){console.log(e+" "+gdrive+" ["+result+"]");return -1;}
  if (result.length > 0) SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  return fileCount;
}
```

the try catch statement is where it fails saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>   1dmDV2qdnU2Qqrg6mr-sxD8JaQncTUNqn []

This doesn't occur every time the folder has no files, or every time it has no folders, I don't think.

So how can result sometimes be undefined, when it is clearly defined as result = [], and if it *is* undefined, why isn't it being captured by the "if result == undefined" line?

Some lines removed for clarity (just the file counting stuff), I wasn't using result up in that part anyway.

Comment: Your error probably stems from the 4th argument that you pass to your `getRange()` ie. `result[0].length`. It could be that the 0th element in your `result` array does not have a `length` property.

Comment: Ok, I thought to check the length of the array in general and that seeems to be fixing my problem. Why doesn't if (result == []) work?

Comment: In your script, it's `var result = [];`. And `result` is compared with `[]`. At Javascript, in this case, the object is compared as the reference. By this, `result == []` is always `false`. When you want to confirm whether `result` is `[]`, how about modifying to `result.length == 0`?

Comment: Did you mean to do something with `fileCount`?

Comment: You have two declarations for `folder`. `var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(gdrive);//here
  var fileCount=0;
  var folders=folder.getFolders();
  var result=[];
  while (folders.hasNext()){
    var folder = folders.next();//and here`

Comment: yes, changing to check for result.length == 0 fixed it for me, Tanaike I didn't know that (result == []) will always be false

Comment: Tanaike can you make your answer the answer? I'm sure coopers works as well but yours was the change that fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your script, `result` is declared as `var result = [];`. And `result` is compared with `[]`.

At Javascript, in this case, the object is compared as the reference. By this, `result == []` is always `false`. In order to confirm whether `result` is `[]` which is empty, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
result == []
```

#### To:

```
result.length == 0
```

or

```
!result.length
```

#### References:

- [Array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)
- [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7837456/7108653)

  - I think that also this thread might help for understanding this situation.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
function getFolderCount(){
  var fldr=DriveApp.getFolderById('folderId');
  var subfldrCount=0;
  var subfolders=fldr.getFolders();
  var result=[];
  while (subfolders.hasNext()){
    var subfolder=subfolders.next();
    result.push([++subfldrCount,subfolder.getName(),subfolder.getId()]);
  }
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("FoldersPlusCounts");
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1, 1,result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
```